# Cassandra and PDO

Tags: php, pdo, cassandra, cql3

I've installed the [YACassandraPDO](https://github.com/Orange-OpenSource/YACassandraPDO) driver for PHP. I have a schema where one table has a `average DOUBLE` field and is using CQL3/Casssandra 2.0.

And attempted the following:

```
$stmt = $this->connection->prepare('INSERT INTO a (average) VALUES (:average)');
$stmt->bindValue(':average', 2.2);
$stmt->execute();
```

This cause a `CQLSTATE[HY000] [2] Invalid STRING constant (2.2) for average of type double`.

How should I go about getting this to work?

Seeing that PDO does not have any way of specifying types of a float/double ([docs](http://www.php.net/manual/en/pdo.constants.php)), it is starting to look like PDO is no-go unless I want my field types to all be of type TEXT which in turn has other undesirable implications.

Comment: If you want types to be text, then redesign the table and alter every column to be `text`

Comment: Try to use quotes around `:average` in the query.. Does it work?

Comment: @RoyalBg I do not want it to be stored in cassandra as text...

Comment: @hek2mgl I'm not sure what you're trying to accomplish with quotes? The bindValue escapes the 2.2 to "2.2" which is the problem - Cassandra will not accept a string in place of a double

Comment: @KasperMiddelboePetersen I was just an idea. I don't have cassandra for testing. Other dbs like mysql will accept `'2.2'` as a double. Have you tried it?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It seems that it is expecting a string by default, as you have already found out. According to the documentation on github, and admittedly a little bit counterintuitively, you need to use the PARAM_INT for double, too. So try this instead:

```
$stmt->bindValue(':average', 2.2, PDO::PARAM_INT);
or maybe even
$stmt->bindValue(':average', "2.2", PDO::PARAM_INT);
```

The types are defined as follows:

```
text        PDO::PARAM_STR 
blob        PDO::PARAM_STR 
varchar     PDO::PARAM_STR 
uuid        PDO::PARAM_INT
int         PDO::PARAM_INT
bigint      PDO::PARAM_INT
float       PDO::PARAM_INT
double      PDO::PARAM_INT
decimal     PDO::PARAM_INT
```

[See the relevant "binding" section in the driver's documentation on github](https://github.com/Orange-OpenSource/YACassandraPDO/wiki#binding) for more information.

Hope that actually works. I do not have a running php test environment to test this.